# Onmouseclick change another image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three images: the first is a light switch, the second is an "off" light bulb and the third is an "on" light bulb. When a user clicks on the light switch image, I would like it to change the "off" light bulb image into the "on" light bulb image. Is this possible?

These are the images:

[image: switch]  [image: off light bulb] [image: on light bulb]

Javascript:

```
img2=new Image();
img2.src="images/RCS/lightbul2-250.gif";
img3=new Image();
img3.src="images/RCS/lightbuld1.gif";

function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById('myImage').src=img2.src;
}
function changeImage2() {
document.getElementById('myImage').src=img3.src;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img id="myImage" onmouseover="changeImage()" onmouseout="changeImage2()" border="0" width="250" height="141" src="images/RCS/lightbulb1-100.gif">
```

Comment: Yes, what do you have so far?

Comment: Just a heads up - it is far easier to use JQuery to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also achieve this without JQuery by using if/else statements.

HTML Markup:

```
<a href="#" onClick="changeImage()"><img src="lightSwitch.jpg"></a>
<img id="myImage" src="lightOff.jpg">
```

Javascript:

```
function changeImage() {
    if(document.getElementById('myImage').src == 'lightOff.jpg') {
        document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'lightOn.jpg';
    } else if(document.getElementById('myImage').src == 'lightOn.jpg') {
        document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'lightOff.jpg';
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5bsdw/)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#switch').click(function(){
          $('#bulb').attr('src', 'bulbOn.jpg');
     });
});
```

Just give your switch image an ID of 'switch' and your original bulb image an id of 'bulb'.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, just attach a class to the lightswitch image and do something like this:

HTML MARKUP:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLSuu.gif" class="lightswitch">

<div id="container">
<div id="bulb" class=""></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.toggle-off { display: none; }

#bulb { height: 100%; width: 100%; background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9EOR.gif')    
center center no-repeat;  }

.bulb-on { background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnKyp.gif') center center no-repeat 
!important; }

.lightswitch { float: left; }

.clear { clear: both; }

#container { width: 300px; height: 300px; float: right; }
```

​
THEN USE JQUERY:

```
$('.lightswitch').click(function() {
   $('#bulb').toggleClass('bulb-on');
});​
```

Basically what this is doing is: once the lightswitch picture is clicked, it is checking to see if either the ID of BULB has a class of "bulb-on". If it doesn't, it is adding it. If it does, it is removing it.

You may also want to style the lightswitch so that it has a hand cursor as if it is a link, like so:

```
.lightswitch { cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; }
```

JS FIDDLE HERE:

http://jsfiddle.net/SDRQU/

Comment: The only issue I see with Danny's answer above is that it will not allow you TOGGLE the lightswitch I do not believe. This solution above will turn the light bulb on and off.

If that is what you are attempting, this is the solution. There is probably a slightly cleaner way to do it, but this works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have now set this up, however the lightbulb is not showing on the webpage, only the lightswitch?

Comment: I am making a JSFiddle now. I will link it here when I am done.

Comment: As I previously thought, this was WAY more easily accomplished.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SDRQU/  There you can see the CSS, JQuery and HTML markup I used to achieve this. I will update my above post here as well.

If this is what you needed, can you mark my post as your answer please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function altsrcImg(cnImage) {
    var src = document.getElementById(cnImage).src;
    var alt = document.getElementById(cnImage).alt;
    document.getElementById(cnImage).src = alt;
    document.getElementById(cnImage).alt = src;
}
</script>
<img id="cnImage" src="TnKyp.gif" alt="l9EOR.gif"><br>
<img id="cnImage" onClick="altsrcImg(this.id)" src="wLSuu.gif">
```

I am using a general javascript I wrote to flip between image specified as src and another specified as alt.

The above script works. [See this](http://notes.lakdiva.org/javas/altlight.html).

However if I change the image order it does not work. 
Probably because there is now two src associated with `id="cnImage"`. 
I am still learning the basics of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<img src="../switch1.png"  id="switch1" onclick="ON(1)"> <img
    src="../switch2.png"  id="switch2" onclick="OFF(0)"> <img
    src="../lighON.png"  id="ON"> <img src="../lighOFF.png" id="OFF">
           <script> function ON(X){ if(X=1) { document.getElementById("ON").style.display=block;
    document.getElementById("OFF").style.display=none;
    document.getElementById("switch1").style.display=block;
    document.getElementById("switch2").style.display=none; }else{
    document.getElementById("ON").style.display=none;
    document.getElementById("OFF").style.display=block;
    document.getElementById("switch1").style.display=none;
    document.getElementById("switch2").style.display=block; } y=0;
    </script>
```

```
css
```

```css
#ON,#OFF{position:absolute;top:30px;left:30px;width:50px; height:50px;}
    #switch1,#switch2{position:absolute;top:30px;left:330px;width:50px; height:50px;}
    #OFF,#switch2{dispay:none;}
```