# Changing image with onClick from an unordered list of images (colours)

Tags: javascript

this is my first question here so I hope i'm as clear as I can be.

I'm creating a product page and have an unordered list of images that represent various colours that a product comes in. When I click one of the colours i'd like the product image to update to show the product with that colour.

I achieved some basic functionality using [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210164/onmouseclick-change-another-image)

Here's the code I have so far -

```js
function changeImage() {
    if(document.getElementById('classic400').src == 'http://i.imgur.com/DxkuRlE.jpg') {
        document.getElementById('classic400').src = 'http://i.imgur.com/02UH7UA.jpg';
    }else {
      //Not sure
    }
}
```

```css
.colours {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

li img {
 height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="colours">
    <ul>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/doLMeIi.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZQdTrml.jpg" onClick="changeImage()"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PeidQGD.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GcGpWy5.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/AWCzo9N.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yTeF0qu.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/i35OBvT.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
        <ul>  
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/LNeGCoB.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/IOpBiQ8.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/jZmYBY8.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/mfpTmrC.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/N2FH527.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/DbS3cRs.jpg"></li>
          <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/94D0biy.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
              </div>
              
<div class="product">
    <img id="classic400" src="http://i.imgur.com/DxkuRlE.jpg" height= "400px">     
</div>
```

This allows me to click the second image in the list and change the product image. From this point on I don't know how to incorporate it to use all the other colours.

Do I continue to write if / else statements to use all the colours or is there a better / neater way to do this?

I've also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajaggysnake/u7yo633a/) with the above code to illustrate what I'm talking about.

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with Arrays?

Comment: To a degree, most of my knowledge thus far comes from sources such as Treehouse and Codecademy. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a totally different approach but I believe offers a much clear solution:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test code</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div>
            <img src="http://mlb-s1-p.mlstatic.com/camiseta-personalizada-com-smiles-ideogramas-simbolos-13992-MLB3293421990_102012-O.jpg">
            <ul>
                <li data-src="http://mlb-s1-p.mlstatic.com/camiseta-personalizada-com-smiles-ideogramas-simbolos-13992-MLB3293421990_102012-O.jpg">Yellow</li>
                <li data-src="http://images.clipartof.com/thumbnails/67235-Royalty-Free-RF-Clipart-Illustration-Of-A-Happy-Blue-Emoticon-Face-Smiley.jpg">Blue</li>
                <li data-src="http://www.cliparthut.com/clip-arts/169/green-smiley-face-clip-art-169032.png">Green</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script>

        document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var target = e.target;

            // If not one of the `li` items, ignore it
            if (!target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "li") {
                return;
            }

            // If it doesn't have a data-src, ignore it
            var newSrc = target.getAttribute("data-src");
            if (!newSrc) {
                return;
            }

            // IN this case, we know exactly how the DOM is layed out
            // and that the parent we want is two levels up.
            // Looping through this is sometimes a better idea.
            var parentDiv = target.parentNode.parentNode;

            var img = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
            console.log(img);

            img.src = newSrc;         
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll have to wait to test that fully as i'm at work, looks like it works though, thank you very much!

Comment: It is, in my opinion, a more modern approach to the problem.  I wrote it so that it should run on any fairly modern JavaScript system (IE8+) and I believe it keeps the HTML about as clean as it can be kept, while keeping related information together.

Comment: I finally got around to playing with this. It works but I now have further questions! It targets the img src in the same div, is there a way to target an img src in a different div? Secondly, the clickable area on the list items are tiny and outside of the image. How can I increase the size so the user can click anywhere on the image (list item) to change the image? Thank you for your help, very much appreciated!

Comment: I added an extra parentNode to the parentDiv variable and solved that issue - now to increase the clickable area.

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. The image in the list item seems to cover the clickable area. Any ideas?