# Increasing clickable area of image in an unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question follows on from a question that was answered for me a couple of days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32938228/changing-image-with-onclick-from-an-unordered-list-of-images-colours). I followed up with today's question but it unfortunately hasn't been answered and i'm not sure how to go about it.

```js
        document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var target = e.target;

            // If not one of the `li` items, ignore it
            if (!target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "li") {
                return;
            }

            // If it doesn't have a data-src, ignore it
            var newSrc = target.getAttribute("data-src");
            if (!newSrc) {
                return;
            }

            // IN this case, we know exactly how the DOM is layed out
            // and that the parent we want is two levels up.
            // Looping through this is sometimes a better idea.
            var parentDiv = target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

            var img = parentDiv.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
            console.log(img);

            img.src = newSrc;         
        });
```

```css
.colours {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: inline;
}

li img {
 height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-img"> 
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DxkuRlE.jpg" height="50%" width="50%">
      </div> 
      <div class="colours">
        <ul>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/DxkuRlE.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/doLMeIi.jpg"></li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/fnWJNDi.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GcGpWy5.jpg"></li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/xt6cysI.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/AWCzo9N.jpg"></li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/GEcT7Hn.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yTeF0qu.jpg"></li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/iWRara7.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/i35OBvT.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/OgbJcRe.jpg">"Red"</li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/duO7fk0.jpg">"Grey/White"</li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/j74Up5A.jpg">"Green"</li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/kjFduEb.jpg">"Black"</li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/jHaxFe7.jpg">"Off White"</li>
        </ul>
```

By clicking a colour it's supposed to change the main image. In the first row i'm using an image as the list item. It seems to "cover" the clickable area. I have to click outside the image (bottom left or right) to change the main image.

Whereas on the second row using just text instead of an image, all of this is clickable and proceeds to change the main image.

My question is as follows, how do I increase the clickable area for the images or somehow stop the image "covering" the clickable area?

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajaggysnake/p8dcaqmn/) shows the code that i'm trying to implement.

Thanks, Jaggy.

Comment: Can I use jquery for javascript part?

Comment: Yeah, i'm open to anything!

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/p8dcaqmn/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try below changes. The issues was your js was checking for li target but for images target was returning img element. Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p8dcaqmn/7/

complete html (added id for main img)

```
<div class="main-img"> 
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DxkuRlE.jpg" height="50%" width="50%" id="mainImg">
      </div> 
      <div class="colours">
        <ul>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/DxkuRlE.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/doLMeIi.jpg"</li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/fnWJNDi.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GcGpWy5.jpg"></li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/xt6cysI.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/AWCzo9N.jpg"></li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/GEcT7Hn.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/yTeF0qu.jpg"></li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/iWRara7.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/i35OBvT.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/OgbJcRe.jpg">"Red"</li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/duO7fk0.jpg">"Grey/White"</li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/j74Up5A.jpg">"Green"</li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/kjFduEb.jpg">"Black"</li>
          <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/jHaxFe7.jpg">"Off White"</li>
        </ul>
```

js

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var target = e.target;


    // If not one of the `li` items, ignore it
    if (!target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "li" || !target.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img") {
        return;
    }

    // If it doesn't have a data-src, ignore it
    var newSrc = target.getAttribute("data-src");
    if (!newSrc) {
        newSrc = target.parentNode.getAttribute("data-src");
        if (!newSrc)
            return;
    }

    // IN this case, we know exactly how the DOM is layed out
    // and that the parent we want is two levels up.
    // Looping through this is sometimes a better idea.
    var parentDiv = target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

    var img = document.getElementById("mainImg");
    console.log(img);

    img.src = newSrc;         
});
```

css (only li changed)

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: If I use this example twice on the one page then clicking the colour changes all of the images. Even if I change the main image ID it still doesn't work. What's the reason for this?

With the old code it would work for several instances (5) on the page. Now it changes all the images from one colour panel. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: try this updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p8dcaqmn/8/ I have changed classes for both the section. This fiddle is having 2 instances.

Comment: Ah I see what you did, thanks for that update as well. Definitely need to get my head in the books again! I don't have a high enough rep to up vote but thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can help you.

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/p8dcaqmn/6/)

HTML

```
<div class="main-img">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DxkuRlE.jpg">
</div>
<div class="colours">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/DxkuRlE.jpg" class="active">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/doLMeIi.jpg" />
        </li>
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/fnWJNDi.jpg">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/GcGpWy5.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/xt6cysI.jpg">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AWCzo9N.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/GEcT7Hn.jpg">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yTeF0qu.jpg">
        </li>
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/iWRara7.jpg">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/i35OBvT.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/OgbJcRe.jpg">"Red"</li>
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/duO7fk0.jpg">"Grey/White"</li>
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/j74Up5A.jpg">"Green"</li>
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/kjFduEb.jpg">"Black"</li>
        <li data-src="http://i.imgur.com/jHaxFe7.jpg">"Off White"</li>
    </ul>
```

Css

```
.main-img {
    background: url(http://s21.postimg.org/404u5wqrr/loader.gif) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
}
.main-img img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.colours {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

li.active {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

li img {
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
    $('.thumbnails').on({
        click: function () {
            $('.main-img img').attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
            $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        }
    }, 'li');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution!

Comment: I implemented this and it works perfectly, thank you!